# Odd timezone offset when converting

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, timezone, utc

I am trying to use UTC wherever possible. Now I found the following strange behaviour and I really don't understand what ist happening. It would be great, if someone could give advice.

Note: I write my code in the Google Apps Script Editor.

I use the following code to create a date and get the output in my local timezone:

```
var testDate = Date.UTC(2022,0,1,0,0,0,0);
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(testDate), 'Europe/Berlin', 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm'));
```

The result is `01.01.2022 01:00`, as expected, because 'Europe/Berlin' is 1 hour behind UTC. So if I wanted the output to be `01.01.2022 00:00` I would try the following:

```
var testDate = Date.UTC(2021,11,31,23,0,0,0);
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(testDate), 'Europe/Berlin', 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm'));
```

But the result I get is: `01.01.2022 12:00`
Can anybody hint me to why my expectation is wrong?

(I hope my English is okay.)

Comment: `Date.UTC(2021,11,31,23,0,0,0` did you really mean November 31? In my part of the world November has 30 days only.

Comment: The month-argument ist zero-based (0 = January), so 11 = December.

Comment: ` 'Europe/Berlin' is 1 hour behind UTC ` did you mean **ahead** ?

Comment: @Kos That is correct. Maybe a little lost in translation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we can *directly* answer the question, because it looks like the issue is that `Utilities.formatDate` uses 12:00 for midnight (which is one of two valid ways of writing midnight in many systems, especially when using a 12-hour clock, though usually you follow it with something indicating it's 12:00 a.m., not 12:00 p.m.). For instance, here's an example of another formatter doing that because I'm explicitly telling it to use 12-hour time:

```js
const testDate = Date.UTC(2022,0,1,0,0,0,0);
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {
    hour12: true,
    timeZone: "UTC",
    timeStyle: "short",
}).format;
console.log(dateTimeFormat(testDate));
```

So you'd have to look at `Utilities.formatDate` to see if it has an option for 24-hour time or at least using `00:00` for midnight, like some other formatters do.

But more fundamentally, if you're trying to format in UTC, I wouldn't play offset games to do it, not least because Berlin isn't *always* one hour offset from UTC, sometimes it's two hours offset (daylight saving time).¹ Instead, I'd have a formatter that uses the UTC accessors on `Date` (`getUTCHours`, `getUTCMonth`, etc.) to build the string rather than using the local time version. Either some library, or something that uses [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). For example:

```js
const testDate = Date.UTC(2022,0,1,0,0,0,0);
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de", {
    timeZone: "UTC",
    dateStyle: "medium",
    timeStyle: "short",
}).format;
// Outputs "01.01.2022, 00:00", which is close to but
// not quite the same as your desired format
console.log(dateTimeFormat(testDate));

// Outputs your desired format, but may not be flexible across locales
const dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de", {
    timeZone: "UTC",
    dateStyle: "medium",
}).format;
const timeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de", {
    timeZone: "UTC",
    timeStyle: "short",
}).format;
console.log(`${dateFormat(testDate)} ${timeFormat(testDate)}`);
```

---

¹ Remember that UTC is unchanging, it doesn't have daylight saving time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of the daylight saving time issue and the implication in an actual application.But my question relates more to the specific example in my question. I did use 23 for the hour value and got the result as mentioned and can't understand why.

Comment: @OleRehr - Doh! You did, didn't you! I looked too quickly and saw the 11 in the month slot. Sorry about that! I've updated the answer for what I suspect the issue is, but really it's going to be down to what `Utilities.formatDate` does.

Comment: @OleRehr try `HH` instead of `hh`, or `KK`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#:~:text=H,day%20(0%2D23)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Your answer is very helpful! I'm still falling into every trap when it comes to date and time.

Comment: @Kos - JavaScript, not Java. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do you mean

Comment: @Kos - You've linked to Java's `SimpleDateFormat` class, but the question is about JavaScript code, not Java code. (Your suggestion of using a 24-hour token is probably a good one -- and something I missed -- but the link isn't useful if `formatDate` doesn't just happen to use all the same tokens as `SimpleDateFormat`. Is `Utilities.formatDate` a standard GAS thing that uses the same tokens? My bad if so and that's common knowledge, I just would have linked to GAS docs instead...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh wait, I thought apps script with in java

Comment: @Kos - :-) Nope, JavaScript. I think the JavaScript engine GAS uses was Rhino for a while (or Narwhal), so that may be what you're thinking of, but these days I think they use V8.

Comment: @Kos, sorry for the late answer, using HH really solved the mystery. :-) GAS uses V8 (JavaScript).

Comment: So you mean V8 uses Java at some point, like dates and time?

Comment: @Kos - No. I **think** that some years ago, Google Apps Script (GAS) ran on Rhino (or Narwhal), both of which are JavaScript engines that run on top of the Java Virtual Machine. But more recently, GAS was upgraded to V8, which has nothing to do with Java at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well Ctrl_+F on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities for "java" still finds actually Java references, not JavaScript, so looks like under the hood Apps Script mimics (or still uses) Java

Comment: @Kos - Yeah, I see what you mean.